# Compiling renderscript source code

Tags: java, android, git, renderscript

As I mentioned in my previous post ([Compiling renderscript code at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636681/compiling-renderscript-code-at-runtime)), I try to compile renderscript code at runtime.
As suggested by Kietz I need to alter the ScriptC class from which all generated java classes derive.
Making my own class that extends Script fails because I cannot invoke the constructor of this super class.

This snippet of the code

```
public class RuntimeScriptC extends Script {
       private static final String TAG = "RuntimeScriptC";

   protected RuntimeScriptC(int id, RenderScript rs) {            
       super(id, rs);       

   }
```

gives me this error:

```
The constructor Script(int, RenderScript) is undefined
```

My next idea was to add my own class to the renderscript source code and compile it to create
a new .jar. I found the source code on [git](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/rs) but have no idea how to only build the renderscript package.

Edit:
I just found out that the constructor of `Script.java` is package private. That's why I can't access the constructor in my own class. If I can compile the renderscript sources myself I could place my own class into the package and access it.

**New question: Where can I find the renderscript sources and how can I compile them?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RenderScript's source can be found at [android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/rs/java/android/renderscript), along with that of the rest of Android. If you want to rebuild Android or a part of it, [here](http://source.android.com/source/developing.html) is probably a good place to start.

However, that is overkill. If you can't modify `ScriptC` directly, just inherit from it. This is possible because the only methods you need from `ScriptC` are its protected constructors. For example, I wrote `HackedScriptC` which does nothing but forward its arguments to `ScriptC()`:

```
package com.example.android.rs.extremehax;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.ScriptC;

public class HackedScriptC extends ScriptC {

    public HackedScriptC(RenderScript rs, Resources resources, int id) {
        // simple passthru to the only constructor that ScriptC_mono uses
        super(rs, resources, id);
    }

}
```

It can now be substituted for `ScriptC` in a glue class:

```
package com.example.android.rs.extremehax;
// ...     
public class ScriptC_mono extends HackedScriptC { 
    // otherwise identical glue class...
```

In your case, you would not invoke the super constructor `ScriptC(RenderScript,Resources,int)` because that invokes `internalCreate`, which you want to override. Instead, invoke `ScriptC(int,RenderScript)`.

Comment: Did you end up rebuilding RenderScript?

Comment: It's not easy to only rebuild the renderscript part. I had to compile the full android package, so that was a no go. In the internalCreate is a openRawResource function. openRawResource is a function of the Resource class, we made our own Resource class that we give to the constructor of ScriptC. The openRawResource now points to a directory of our own chosing where we can add/change the .bc file.

Comment: Any chance you could share your source? I'm very interested in how your project turned out

Comment: I do not know that I am allowed to share our code since it's for a thesis. I will ask the company what I may and may not do and will update you on this matter asap!

Comment: Sorry for the long reply time. But we have released the source code on [github](https://github.com/degoossez/OVSR) with an MIT license. The project is not yet fully debugged but should be pretty stable. There will be a README soon on how to setup the renderscript compile server and how to connect the app with it. I think what you would like to see is the  "src/com/denayer/ovsr/MyResources.java" file and it's implementation (RenderScriptTemplate function) in "src/com/denayer/ovsr/RsScript.java". If you would like any more information feel free to reply or mail me on the email in the license.